# Why a same JComponent object cannot be displayed when added more than once?

Tags: java, swing

Example:

```
public class JFrameTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JButton button = new JButton("Hello!");
            frame.getContentPane().add(button);
            frame.getContentPane().add(button);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

In the above example 'button' object is added only once even though there are no errors. The reason why I ask this is, I would like to add a same JPanel object on JFrame and on JDialog (on some table double click for edit/delete feature). I am able to solve it by having two JPanel objects but just wanted to know why it is not possible.

Comment: The simple answer is that you can't because the javadocs say that you can't.

Comment: "As a conveniance `add` and its variants…have been overridden to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary. This means you can write: "  `frame.add(button)`—[`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only add Swing components once in the Swing hierarchy as you already found out. This is documented in the ['Using top-level components tutorial'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

> Each GUI component can be contained only once. If a component is already in a container and you try to add it to another container, the component will be removed from the first container and then added to the second.

Not completely sure whether there were technical limitations that let to this decision, but I could imagine that for example the [`getParent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) method would give strange results if you were able to add the same component to two `Container`s

Comment: The "technical limitation" could well be that a components' fields hold the computed size and location of the component relative to its parent and/or its window.  If a component can be in a container (or containers) more than once, then the fields can't hold the relevant information for both sets of locations / sizes.

Comment: @StephenC that certainly is a possibility. I was also thinking in the line of problems with event handling (like `mouseEntered`) and passing events down the chain of components

Comment: Anything, related to one object will lead to conflict, whether it's size, location/eventhandling, colour, font, blah blah. You name it and that thing will give conflict as to which refers to which one :-)